# my code is only returning one section of the code

Tags: php

```
<?php
    if(!$product_kit_rage) {
        echo '<a href ="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Purchase Now</button></a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href ="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Download</button></a>';
    }
?>
```

This code only seems to display the first section of the echo

example:

```
<a href ="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Purchase Now</button></a>
```

the variable is already stored in via

```
include_once("/home/user/public_html/resource/session.php");
```

my aim is when its got a value of 1 in product_kit_rage it returns

```
<a href ="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Download</button></a>
```

Comment: if( $product_kit_rage != 1 ) {}

Comment: Is the included file definitely setting a variable in the correct scope?

Comment: Where is $product_kit_rage being set? I would also use a bool.

Comment: **Warning**: Your HTML is invalid. `<button>` elements are not permitting inside `<a>` elements. If it a link use a link. If it is a button, use a button. Apply CSS to get the presentation you desire.

Comment: [*"also had to alter the line in session to go with it"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510477/my-code-is-only-returning-one-section-of-the-code#comment81977141_47510586) - Session, what session??

Comment: Why are you being unresponsive in comments? You've been asked/given many comments, yet you say nothing, why is that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to show download button when product_kit_rage is 1:

```
      <?php
      if ( $product_kit_rage == 1 ) {
          echo '<a href ="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Download</button></a>';
      } else {
          echo '<a href ="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Purchase Now</button></a>';
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: thank you thats helped also had to **alter the line in session to go with it**